# Looping user defined table type in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a user-defined table type

```
create TYPE [dbo].[AddressList] AS TABLE (
    [Address] [NVARCHAR](MAX) not null
);
```

I am taking that table in my stored procedure as input parameter (it contains list of string)

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ScanAddress]
    @list AddressList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- need to iterate it here
END
```

I want to iterate it

For example I have a table `Address` in my DB and if address in my input exist in DB then I want to return `Status=1` else `Status=0` in just one call. So it should return

```
select address, Status 
from #temp
```

something kind of..

Comment: Tag dbms product used.  (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: @jarlh Pretty sure (based on syntax) - it is MS SQL.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, yes, most probably. But it's better if OP does the tagging.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in fact you don't need any loop here.

You can simply make join from your table variable to your DB table and return 0 if there is no match and 1 otherwise.

Something like (here `column_you_need` denotes column in your table holding address to compare):

```
select 
    T.Address,
    case when T1.column_you_need is null then 0 else 1 end as Status 
from @list as T
    left outer join Address as T1 on T.Address = T1.column_you_need
```